# grails hibernate create a table with exactly one row

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I need to create a table **with exactly one row**.

I have a domain class, for example `Book`, which has property `Year`.

```
class Book {

  Integer year

  static mapping = {
     ...
  }

}
```

What do I need to write in a domain class?

Comment: I don't think you declare a limit for the number of rows. You can have an unique constraint on year, would this be enough?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you need only one book record with year `2013`, then you can define your constraint as

```
class Book {
  Integer year
  static constraints = {
     year inList: [2013], unique: true
  }
}
```

`unique: true` will not let you create records with duplicate `year` and `inList` will make sure you have one and only one `year` which is 2013. Both the constraints will pass for the first insert and will fail for subsequent inserts/updates. Therefore, you end up with only one record in `Book` with Year 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the GORM event you would use to accomplish this `beforeInsert` doesn't allow rejection of the insert (as of Grails 2.2.2). `beforeUpdate` does, but that doesn't help you in this case.

There are two solutions that come to mind:

- using a service method to perform the decision making of whether or not to insert. However if another class uses the domain class directly, you have no automatic insert rejection.
- Create a custom Hibernate [PreInsertEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/PreInsertEventListener.html) that checks if the table already has data.

Burt Beckwith outlined using a custom Hibernate event listener for creating effectively read-only domain classes in his [gr8Conf session from 2011](http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/gorm-burt-beckwith2011) if you would like an example of the latter.